# How to remove a group of characters from a phone string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am willing to know how can I check if the a phone number contain the following prefixes `+44`, `0044` or `0` and if so it will be removed? I know I to remove a number of characters or a substring but how do I check if that substring is in the beginning?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could with regex [**`/^(\+44|0044|0)/g`**](https://regex101.com/r/sBP0NJ/1)

```js
function rem(str){
  return str.replace(/^(\+44|0044|0)/g,'')
}


console.log(rem('0044987987'));
console.log(rem('04478687'));
console.log(rem('+447783'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` to check the index of those prefix.

```
"+44-----".indexOf("+44") // returns 0
```

That should be enough for what you want.

Comment: And what if there is 0 or 0044 and the phone number looks like 07759040922 or 00447750400449

Comment: You just replace the IndexOf("0") with whatever pattern you want , if it returns 0, then it means its on the start of the string, you can just loop through all the things you want to check for and if they appear at start, just remove them.

In cases where you want to check for 0 and for 0044, then you need to check with the specific order, so first check for 0044, then for 0

Answer (score 0):

You can simply test against a regex pattern.

Or use it for a replace.

```js
const re_tel44 = /^[+]?0{0,2}(?:44)?(\d{5,})$/;

let phonenumber = '+4412345';

console.log(re_tel44.test(phonenumber));

if(re_tel44.test(phonenumber))
  phonenumber = phonenumber.replace(re_tel44, '$1');

console.log(phonenumber);
```